# Javascript/jQuery: Why is the focus event not firing on an input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, forms, input

I'm trying to attach a simple focus/blur event listener via the `.live()` jQuery method to my inputs but what I'm noticing is that the `focus` event is not firing whereas the `blur` event is.

Strange… was hoping you may have an idea of why this is happening.

Here is the code:

```
function rowHighlight() {
  var form = $('form.register'),
      ele = {};

      form.find('label').each(function(i) {
        var link = this.htmlFor;
        form.find('label[for='+link+'],input[name='+link+'],textarea[name='+link+']').wrapAll('<span class="row"/>');
      });

      ele.row = $('form > .row');
      ele.inputs = ele.row.find('input');


      $.each(ele.inputs, function(i) {
          $(this).focus(function() {
              console.log('hello'); // this will fire.
          });
        $(this).live('focus blur', function(e) {
            console.log('current event type: '+e.type); // the focus on this will not fire!?
            ( e.type=='focus' ? console.log('focussed') : console.log('blurred') )
        });
      });    
}
rowHighlight();
```

`$(this).focus…` was just put it as a debugging thing and removing it does not make the `focus` on the `live` listener work…

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for stopping by.

Jannis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
$.each(ele.inputs, function(i) {
```

to this line:

```
ele.inputs.each(function() {
```

**Explanation:**

There are two forms of `each()` in jQuery.

Iterating over a map or array:

```
$.each([1,2,3], function(index, value){

});
```

**or**, when iterating over a jQuery object:

```
$("a").each(function(){

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

`$(this)` means what you would expect only in the second use:

```
$("a").each(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

**Live vs. Bind:**

```
$("a").click(someClickEventHandler);
```

... binds the `someClickEventHandler` click event handler to every `a` tag that exists when this is executed.

```
$("a").live("click", someClickEventHandler);
```

... binds the `someClickEventHandler` click event handler to every `a` tag that exists when this is executed, AND it will also bind the `someClickEventHandler` click event handler to every `a` event that will ever exist. For example, if an `a` tag is created from an Ajax response, the event handler will automatically be bound.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked wonderfully though the `.live` still wouldn't work. Changing `.live` to `.bind` however made it work.

Comment: `live()` binds an event handler automatically when passed a selector it should target, not a specific object. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the Live vs Bind addition! Much appreciated.